# Eigenvalue of square of operator

Tags: linear-algebra

The problem is to prove that if $A^2$ has eigenvalue $\lambda^2$ then $A$ should have one equals to $\lambda$ or  $-\lambda$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that 
\begin{align*}
\det(A^2-\lambda^2 I)&=0 \\
\det(A-\lambda I )(A+\lambda I) &=0
\end{align*}

It is pretty straightforward to draw the conclusion from this.